# Function isn't being called in Node Js using REST API

Tags: node.js, rest

I am writing a code in Node JS, which uses mustache for templating html and REST API as backend.

Here is my code that doesn't work.

```
function setupRoutes(app) {
 const base = app.locals.base;

app.get(`${base}/search.html`,doSearchContent(app));   
app.get(`${base}/:name`,doGetContent(app));     
}

function doSearchContent(app) {
  return async function(req, res) {
    console.log("here");
  }; };
```

When I run my program and go to base/search.html. It never calls the doSearchContent method.

Any idea why and how I can fix this?

EDIT: The doGetContent works as expected. It's when I run the search.html it doesn't

Comment: Can you share what framework you are using? You're using some kind of router.

Answer (score 0):

The express paths should be started with a leading slash. Please change your routes addition to something like this:

```
...
app.get(`/${base}/search.html`,doSearchContent(app));   
app.get(`/${base}/:name`,doGetContent(app));
...
```

Express matches the path of http request against the 'path' provided for all routes to decide which routes must be called. Since the http paths always start with a slash, your routes also must specify those to match.

Answer (score 0):

These lines

```
app.get(`${base}/search.html`,doSearchContent(app));   
app.get(`${base}/:name`,doGetContent(app));
```

are not working as you expect. In Express routes we don't invoke functions directly. Instead, we either pass a *name* of a callback fucntion to invoke, that receives `req` and `res` params, or an anonymous callback. In your case it could be something like this:

```
app.get(`${base}/search.html`,(req, res) => {
    console.log("It's alive!");
    doSearchContent(app);
});   
app.get(`${base}/:name`, (req, res) => { 
    doGetContent(app)
});
```

> The express paths should be started with a leading slash.

This is not true

Comment: I tried using this method. It's alive still isn't being printed

Comment: In OP's example, doSearchContent _returns_ a function so this should still work.

Comment: @Evert Ideally this should work, that's why I am not sure why it isn't working

Comment: @Evert yeah, this is indeed an overlook. @Mike Ross in this case you could prepend your routes with `app.use('*', (req, res, next) => { console.log(req.originalUrl); next() })` to check if you actual route matchs `${base}/search.html`

Comment: @AntonPastukhov I tried that, even that is not getting printed for the search.html page

Answer (score 0):

Have you added search.html file or used a template to build the HTML?

Make sure the template is being called and not the html file.

Other than that your code looks fine and it should work

Comment: I had added an html file. Thanks. I made a template file and it works now :)